# Problem creating equal height columns in CSS

Tags: html, css, xhtml, height

I have been using the examples [here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-2-column.htm) to setup a webpage that has columns with equal heights (using only HTML and CSS), and it is working relatively well. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/df9pR/) is the complete HTML and CSS code that I am using.

Newbie questions:

(1) As you can see, I tried to make the left column (id="column_bottom") have a white (#f5f5f5) background with black text, and the right column (id="content_bottom") with black background with white (#f5f5f5) text, but one side is always overriding the other. What can I do to make it what I want?

(2) Also, you can see in the CSS that I have defined fonts and background colors for body, but somehow that is not carrying through, what should I do?

Thanks!

P.S. I am looking for a pure HTML/CSS solution, and prefer not to use javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close.  In your code, just change your styling to the columns themselves, like so:

```
#content_bottom {
    color: #f5f5f5;
    background:#000000; /* right column background colour */
}

#column_bottom {
    color: #000000;
    background:#f5f5f5; /* left column background colour */
}
```

Comment: A live demo I just finished: http://jsbin.com/anota5/3 (which does the same thing)

Comment: Thanks, the colours work now! But somehow the styles I defined for body in the CSS is not carrying through on my computer. Did I do something wrong there?

Comment: Are you referring to the jsfiddle example or your own code?  In the jsfiddle example (and maybe your code) remove the `<style media="screen" type="text/css"></style>` tags.  This applies to your code as well, unless you're not using a stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

the code below will create two boxes side-by-side and the container will always wrap those boxes, no matter how tall they are. this should solve your issue of having columns of the same height.

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">blah</div>
    <div class="box">blah<br/><br/>blah</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container { position:relative; width:100px; border:1px solid red; }
.box { position:relative; float:left; width:40px; border:1px solid blue; }
.clear { clear:both }
```